# How to override rendering static html for 500 error with json response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Trying to render a JSON response on 500 error in application controller. However, rails still renders the static 500.html as response instead of the supplied JSON.

Tried 404, its rendering the JSON fine.

```
rescue_from StandardError, with: :some_method

def some_method

 render json: {
          message: "error",
          status: 500
        }, status: :internal_server_error

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic status template are served by a Rack exception application. We can override this to be any rack compatible application including our application router.

```
config/application.rb

config.exceptions_app = self.routes

config/routes.rb

get "/404", to: "errors#not_found"

class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
    def not_found
        render status: 404
    end
end
```

P.S. You can also use exception_handler gem to automate this.

### For json response you can follow below procedure

application_controller.rb

```
rescue_from Exception do |e|
   error(e)
 end

 def routing_error
   raise ActionController::RoutingError.new(params[:path])
 end

 protected

 def error(e)

   if env["ORIGINAL_FULLPATH"] =~ /^\/api/
   error_info = {
     :error => "internal-server-error",
     :exception => "#{e.class.name} : #{e.message}",
   }

   render :json => error_info.to_json, :status => 500
   else

     raise e
   end
 end
```

Comment: 404 was fine for me. Is there anything specific to 500 which rails resolves to 500.html on its own ?